# The flume event was truncated

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka, interceptor, flume, sink

Here I'm facing a issue that I receive message from Kafka source, and write a interceptor to extract two fields（dataSoure and businessType） from the kafka message(json format). Here I'm using gson.fromJson(). But the issue is I got below error.

Here I want to know whether the Flume truncate the Flume event when it exceed a limit? If yes, how to setup it to bigger value. As my kafka message always very long, about 60K bytes.

Looking forward reply. Thanks in advance!

> 2015-12-09 11:48:05,665 (PollableSourceRunner-KafkaSource-apply)
>   [ERROR -
>   org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource.process(KafkaSource.java:153)]
>   KafkaSource EXCEPTION, {} com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at
>   line 1 column 4096
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:809)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
>           at com.xxx.flume.interceptor.JsonLogTypeInterceptor.intercept(JsonLogTypeInterceptor.java:43)
>           at com.xxx.flume.interceptor.JsonLogTypeInterceptor.intercept(JsonLogTypeInterceptor.java:61)
>           at org.apache.flume.interceptor.InterceptorChain.intercept(InterceptorChain.java:62)
>           at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.processEventBatch(ChannelProcessor.java:146)
>           at org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource.process(KafkaSource.java:130)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the root cause by debug the source code.
It is becaues I tried to convert event.getBody() to a map using Gson, which is incorrect, as the event.getBody() is a byte[], not a String, which can't be converted. The correct code should be as below:

```
String body = new String(event.getBody(), "UTF-8");   
Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(body, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```